# calculate value of sin 30

Tags: java

I can not find the correct value of sin 30 ,

```
 double degrees = 30.0;
 double radians = Math.toRadians(degrees);
 System.out.println(Math.sin(radians));
```

which produces .499999999 but the exact value matching to calculator is .5

please help me..

Comment: I don't believe that you got that result with `Math.ceil`...

Comment: Floating number arithmetic is bound to suffer from inaccuracy. And `Math.ceil` should give you a double value *rounded up* to closest integer.

Comment: It seems like you should get `1.0` as output there, and not `0.5`.

Comment: @phoeagon. No, `Math.ceil` gives a double value not an integer.

Comment: @RohitJain [sin(30)](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=sin+of+30+degrees&aq=f&oq=sin+of+30+degrees&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) is 0.5

Comment: @Bohemian. Oh boy. Why did you directed that comment at me? By double value I meant `1.0`, which is not the same as integer `1` right?

Comment: I think rounding is helpful for you, maybe you could refer to 
[How to round a number to n decimal places in Java][1].

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java

Comment: @RohitJain Looks like the question was edited significantly after your comment. nm.

Answer (score 1):

`Math.sin(..)` make an interpolation to get a good value, therefore you cannot expect to get exact values as result. In addition while interpolating the sin value the problems of float/double arithmetic is an other issue.

Comment: The calculator does the same, but why output there is 0,5? is the question

Comment: @AlexWien: As far as I know the arithmetic in a calculator for the approximation has more digits than the display and is rounded before displayed. Also a different algorithm for the  interpolation may be the reason-

Comment: your first part (more digits) is ok, other algo is for sure not the reason